# How to build a multiple choice PHP based answer dependant survey with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, survey

as the title says, I want to make a sort of survey that asks one question at a time. It will have a lot of questions, some of which are based on the answers of the previous questions( like a logic tree, if 'yes' then 'something, if 'no' then 'another thing' ).

The part that I struggle with is, the way to set the database and then the logic behind how to call the next question based on the previous question's answer.

p.s. I realize most of you will consider it a stupid question, for which I'm sorry, but I can't seem to figure this out and it's been bugging me for a while.

Comment: It's not a stupid question, but it's too broad. You need to ask very specific questions about code you have actually written. We're not going to design your application for you.

Comment: I just need some guidelines, I have 2 tables, one for the questions and one for the answers. I know I can use identifiers to connect a question to an answers, but I'm not sure how to call the different questions and "sub-questions" ( picture the tree view ) and the thing I struggle most with is, how to call the next question and its answers based on the previous question's answer without making a new query.

Comment: Those things you struggle with seem like 90% of the design of the application. Anyway, maybe this will be helpful: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: The row for a question could have `yes_id` and `no_id` columns that contain the `question_id` of the question to go to depending on their answer to the current question.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for, something with examples.